# How do I specify a failure message for assert in Rspec/Capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara

In my rspec integration tests, when I have an assertion such as:

```
assert page.has_content? some_value
```

if the assertion fails, it displays:

```
MiniTest::Assertion: 
Failed assertion, no message given
```

The minitest docs say "All assertion methods accept a msg which is printed if the assertion fails" but I cannot find any examples of HOW to specify the message. These are NOT valid syntax:

```
assert("custom fail msg") page.has_content? some_value

assert page.has_content? some_value, "custom fail msg"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
assert page.has_content?(some_value), "custom fail msg"
```

Assuming I have reproduced your error properly, the issue with your second attempt is that Ruby thinks that "custom fail msg" is a parameter of the `page.has_content?` rather than the `assert`. Adding the brackets around the paramaters for the `page.has_content?` should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you - I surely did not see that documented anywhere else, and your explanation makes perfect sense.